# Scifi (probably short story) about an emergency response crew on a futuristic highway system

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I believe this might be in an anthology, unfortunately for me it's not one that I own.  What I remember from the story:

- The crew is assigned to an emergency response "tank" vehicle that patrols the highways.  I think they have LEO/EMS/Fire personnel assigned, or are all cross trained.  They work long shifts, and are sent by a central dispatch to crash scenes.
- I think they were based in Philadelphia (or somewhere on the eastern seaboard)
- The highways are extreme high speed, so the crashes are horrible scenes

I've recently started as a radio operator in the state I live in, and I would dearly love to read this story again.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122493/sf-short-story-about-a-patrol-car-on-a-hyper-highway-at-400-mph-speeds (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 11):

The novella you're thinking of is [Code Three](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1606643002) by Rick Raphael, probably found in [The Mammoth Book of New World Science Fiction: Short Novels of the 1960s](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/088184702X).

Synopsis:

> Ben Martin and Clay Ferguson have got a tough job. In Car 56 -- "Beulah" -- they patrol the super-highways of a future that might have been. Along with Medical-Surgical Officer Kelly Lightfoot, they help keep an insane road system as safe as possible.
>
> Here is a startling and excitingly realistic portrait of regular folks in a future extrapolated from a time when technology was changing at an explosive rate. What if highways just got bigger and bigger, cars faster and faster? How could such be patrolled, when crashes, jams and road rage are the norm?
>
> The answer is an elite paramilitary corp. These dedicated officers, trying to keep reign on a crazed vehicle culture with sixty foot long tank-like patrol cars with 25mm cannon, cranes and full medical suites.

Comment: That is the OP's story for sure. The [original **novella** "Code Three"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55439) is available as a [Project Gutenberg etext](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/19111); the **novel** [*Code Three*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?264971) is a fix-up of the original novella and its **sequel** ["Once a Cop"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55390).

Answer (score 7):

["Station HR972"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?43994) by [Kenneth Bulmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenneth_Bulmer) is a short story about a futuristic highway rescue team; not enough detail in your description for me to be sure if this is the one you have in mind. First published in [*Worlds of Tomorrow*, February 1967](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?62306+c) (available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Worlds_of_Tomorrow_v04n03_1967-02#page/n99/mode/2up)), it was reprinted in two paperback anthologies, [*Nightmare Age*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?24186) and [*Car Sinister*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?6099); if you read it in one of those anthologies, maybe a look at the cover or the table of contents will ring some bells. Or maybe some excerpts from the story will do the trick:

> From here the limits of the ten-mile stretch for which Station HR972 was responsible lay on the one hand behind the swell of the hill and on the other lost in a gentle undulation of the land leading up to Sennocke Forest. The road lay across the countryside like a fat white worm. Transparent roofing arched across the twelve lanes, hanging in a cunning curve of convoluting strength, unbuttressed and unguyed, a free overarching sweep of plastic that membraned the artificial environment of the road from nature's anarchy without.
> Occasionally through whims in the course of the road the northbound twelve lanes could be seen, a silvery-gray rotundity, beyond their own southbound highway. A brooding awareness of waiting sharpened movement on the road, so that the mechanics around the helicopters on the roof landing spots, the medics sitting checking their morning take-over logs in the ready area, the men carrying in supplies, and others carrying away the detritus of the night all moved as though imbued with that breath of waiting.

,,,

> The gray-green plastic surface of the road reflected no highlights. Its semitactile tread hugged the cars to it as they sped imperiously past. Most of the cars so far this morning had selected the inner and center quads. The twelve lanes were divided into three groups of four lanes each, the inner subdivided for heavy trucks and articulateds, and lighter trucks and coaches. Checking the speed radar meters, Bartram saw only six cars traveling at over a hundred and fifty miles an hour, all on the outer two lanes of the center quad.
> An automobile on the inner center quad swept past at ninety miles an hour.
> "The fool!" said Bartram heatedly. Then the high, irritating wail of a police car tailing the laggard telescoped time, and the offending car increased its speed to conform to the law.

...

> High atop the station, in every room, in the rest area, in the garages, on the helicopter spots, above the basins in the washrooms, the auto repair alarm shrilled. Hard on that strident call the alarm for HR972 chittered in harsh counterpoint.
> Chairs crashed back. Coffee cups spilled. Feet hammered concrete. Helicopter vanes whirred into shining invisibility. The place emptied as though a time bomb set for *now* was found between everyone's legs.
> Bartram's earphones said: "HR972. Grid six two eight. Center quad, two outer lanes."
> That was one point two eight miles south of the station, set midway on its ten-mile stretch of road.
> The helicopters rose buzzing. They slanted away steeply, low over the rounded continuous cylinder of the road, jets roaring. Early morning sunshine caught their white paint and dazzled from the red crosses.
> Charlie, the ladder handler, crouched by the open trap in the floor of the chopper. His rough scarred hands grasped the controls, and wind tugged at his white coveralls. Bruce and Pete, the hook men, lay stomach down in front of him, their hands thrust deeply into the gloved remote-control equipment. Bartram glanced back. Everyone in the belly of his lead copter stood at stations, coveralled, helmeted, goggled, packs with their glaring red crosses strapped in regulation positions.

...

> This time they hit the road before the auto repair gangs had lifted all the cars. The outer quad was the high-speed quad. Two hundred, two hundred fifty miles an hour, strictly lane controlled. A pile-up could telescope a hundred cars, radar alarms locked to brakes or no damn radar alarms. Bartram sent support Teams Thirty through Forty to check the cars stopped, undamaged, in back of the incident.
> "Look for internal bleeding, shock, cracked or bruised ribs, general buffeting." He cracked the whip. "You don't have to hit a car to damage yourself. Don't let any through until they've been checked."
> Libby jetted past holding a girl with no legs, her sides with the plastic bags and the pumps hovering beneath.
> The three lanes held a tangle of cars like a child's toy-car box at bedtime.
> Libby's voice screamed, "You can't sew your damn legs until I've replaced the liver and pancreas!"
> Gloria, the limb technician, screamed back: "Well hurry it up, Libby! The legs are out of deep freeze, and they won't wait all day!"

Does that sound like the right story?

Comment: No that's not it - this didn't involve aliens or anything like that.  It was just near-future America.

Comment: What aliens?? The story I suggested may not be the one you're looking for, but there are certainly no aliens in it.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like [the other answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/40921/475) has it already, with Code Three.  An alternative, however, for completeness: a similar crew appears in Kim Stanley Robinson’s *The Gold Coast*, the second book of his [Three Californias trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Californias_Trilogy); it’s set in Southern California, not Philadelphia, but otherwise fits most aspects of the description.